# problem regarding flutter and i don't know how to fix it

Tags: flutter

I've faced this problem; I have created a `DropDownButton` in flutter (`StateFulWidget`) and I have access to the source of items which I have created, which is a `List`.

Through a `map()` function I got the items and injected them into the `DropdownMenuItem` and all went OK. But I want to pass the source of the items as a parameter to the constructor of the object that I will create inside the `runapp()` method, and this didn't work.

One of the reasons that pops up was this:

> - - - EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter
>         ( 7852): The following assertion was thrown building myMenu(dirty,
>         state: mymenu#39f55): I/flutter ( 7852): type 'List' is not a subtype
>         of type 'List>' I/flutter ( 7852): Either the assertion indicates an
>         error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
>         I/flutter ( 7852): more information in this error message to help you
>         determine and fix the underlying cause.

How can this problem be fixed?

Here is my code:

```
class myMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return mymenu(inputData);
  }

  var inputData;
  myMenu(input) {
    this.inputData = input;
  }
}

class mymenu extends State<myMenu> {
  var incomingData;
  var nameees;

  mymenu(input) {
    this.incomingData = input;
    this.nameees = incomingData[0];
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      items: incomingData.map((String name) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: name,
          child: Text(name),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (itemSelectedByUser) {
        setState(() {
          nameees = itemSelectedByUser;
        });
      },
      value: nameees,
     );
  }
}

var names = [

  "Java",
  "kotlin",
  "dart",
  "Flutter"
  "ruby",
  "ruby on Rails",
  "python",
  "django",
  "javascript",
  "nodejs",
  "express.js",
  "vue.js",
  "react.js"
  "Facebook",
  "YouTube",
  "Twitter",
  "Safari",
  "google"
];

var os = ["Windows", "Linux", "MAc", "iOS", "Android"];
var co = ["Samsung", "Apple", "Sony", "Nikon"];
var selectedItem = "Karrar";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access to variables from `StatefulWidget` using a `widget` like the example below

```
class myMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  final inputData;
  myMenu(
      {Key key,
        @required this.inputData,
        })
      : super(key: key);
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => mymenu();


}

class mymenu extends State<myMenu> {
  var nameees;



  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      items: widget.inputData.map((String name) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: name,
          child: Text(name),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (itemSelectedByUser) {
        setState(() {
          nameees = itemSelectedByUser;
        });
      },
      value: nameees,
    );
  }
}
```